# Spotlight in Snow Leopard was instantaneous but has gotten slow, I've tried reindexing

Tags: performance, osx-snow-leopard, spotlight, application-launch

When I first started using Snow Leopard, I used spotlight to launch programs. I would type cmd-space and the first few letters of the program (chr to launch Google Chrome, for example).

This worked great for about a week -- the first result was always the application, and results turned up instantaneously.

Since then Spotlight has gotten progressively slower, to the point that now, if I type "illus" to launch Adobe Illustrator, it takes more than 10 seconds (a loonnng time) to find the Illustrator application. This even though I use it all the time and it's in the recent programs list.

Does anyone know why Spotlight is so slow to find a file near the top of the disk hierarchy that's in frequent use?

I have tried adding and removing various disks etc. from the privacy pane of the Spotlight system settings. Even when I put every disk and folder in the "prevent" list *except* applications, Spotlight is agonizingly slow.

I also tried deleting the spotlight preferences in the preferences folder, and disabled all the "mdimporter" files that were in /Library/Spotlight:

- AppleWorks
- GBSpotlightImporter
- iWork
- LogicPro
- Microsoft Office

Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is to **periodically remove the applications folder from Spotlight using the privacy pane of the System Preferences**. After adding it back, Spotlight speeds up quite a bit.

Comment: After doing this for a few weeks, it is not clear that it helps very much. I did it yesterday, and today Spotlight is slow again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to launch programs quickly in Snow Leopard than using Spotlight (which turned out to be too slow).

1. change the keyboard shortcut for Spotlight (cmd-space) to activate the dock.
2. group your dock icons alphabetically, but by frequency of use within each letter. For example, I use Adobe Photoshop more than Adobe Illustrator so I put Photoshop before Illustrator in the Dock.

Programs beginning with F should go right after the Finder.

Now, I can launch any program by typing command-space then the first letter of the program (and a down arrow or two if necessary).

It's instant, whereas using Spotlight to launch programs meant a 2-3 second wait each time.

Comment: You *have* heard of application launchers, such as Quicksilver, Alfred, Google QSB or LaunchBar, right?

Comment: Of course. I would have used one of them as a last resort. But I prefer to keep my system as simple as possible, and the dock solution works perfectly with no extra installs.

Answer (score 0):

I got a big speed-up when I added my Time Machine disk to the excluded locations in the Privacy tab of Spotlight Preferences (System Preferences > Spotlight).

Before that, it took like 20 seconds just to look up a contact name (which is my most common use case). Now it's almost instantaneous.

I manually reindexed Spotlight after excluding the Time Machine disk using:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

from the command line in Terminal.

Comment: That would help, but I had trouble even without a TM backup. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I definitely get the idea the fight for Spotlight performance is a war of attrition :) I just thought I'd add this response for the benefit of anyone arriving here on search as a possible avenue worth trying.